# storing id in the immediary table (latest not found)

Tags: php, laravel, builder

I have many to many relationships between **posts** and **tags**

The problem is when I want to get the post id and the tag id to link them in their immediary table I did a simple query to do that and I used **latest()** method in laravel query builder and it threw this error:

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::latest does not exist.

This is my store function:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
        'tags'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'required',

      ]);

      $input = $request->all();
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

          if ($input != null) {
            $post = post::create($input);
            $post->tag($tags);
            // the problem is in this two lines
            $post_id = DB::table('posts')->pluck('id')->latest();
            $tagged_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->pluck('id')->latest();
            //
            dd($tagged_id , $post_id);
            $relationship = new post_tagged;
            $relationship->post_id = $post_id;
            $relationship->tagged_id = $tagged_id;
            $relationship->save();
            return redirect('/admin/blog')->with('success' , 'Post added successfully');
          }
          return redirect('/admin/blog');
    }
 }
```

the idea that I want to achieve with those two lines is to get the latest id in the post table and in the tags table (which is the newest post)
and then storing it in the immediary table

***I solved the problem by doing this***

**store function**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
        'tags'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'required',

      ]);

      $input = $request->all();
        $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

          if ($input != null) {
            $post = post::create($input);
            $post->tag($tags);
            $post_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->latest('taggable_id')->first();
            $post_id = $post_id->taggable_id;
            $tagged_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->latest('id')->first();
            $tagged_id = $tagged_id->id;
            $relationship = new post_tagged;
            $relationship->post_id = $post_id;
            $relationship->tagged_id = $tagged_id;
            $relationship->save();
            return redirect('/admin/blog')->with('success' , 'Post added successfully');
          }
          return redirect('/admin/blog');
         }
```

Comment: why don't you use built in relation classes and Eloquent methods like 'BelongsToMany' and 'belongsToMany()'?

Comment: By the way, because the empty value of `$request->all()` is an empty `array`; checking if the `$input` is empty or not is useless. You can innocuously remove the if statement.

Comment: what about `$post_id = DB::table('posts')->latest()->pluck('id');
            $tagged_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->latest()->pluck('id');` ?

Comment: the post and the tags tables already have many to many relationship but the problem is that this relationship works this way first it will go to the immediary table which is post_tagged table and look for the post id and the tag id so it links them together so what i am trying to achieve or what i need to do in this point is assigninig the tag id and the post id to the immediary table so it links each tag with each post it is many to many relationship so it requires an immediary table

Comment: the point in this two lines
 $post_id = DB::table('posts')->pluck('id')->latest(); $tagged_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->pluck('id')->latest(); 
is to get the latest post id which is the newest post and the latest tag id which is also the newest tags 
@Ahmed Nour Jamal El-Din

Comment: you have to notice two things: first thing, you are PLUCKing a table and `pluck()` returns a collection so you have a collection, which  does not have a `latest()` method but builders have. second thing, `latest()` method won't return the latest post! it will just `orderby` your table, you can check it in [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1373)

Comment: depending on what I understand, you need to `orderby` descending first then take the first element like the following:  `post_id = DB::table('posts')->latest()->first()->id; $tagged_id = DB::table('tagging_tagged')->latest()->first->id;`

Comment: thanks for all comments that helped me coming up with this line especially Ahmed Nour Jama El-Din because he gave me the first hint which is that i must use latest directly afetr the table name